# Type a number and add it to an existing value somewhere else, almost like data entry

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a set of VBA code that allows me to type a number in a specific cell, press a button, and that number gets added on to a different, ongoing cell?

For example, I type in £10, and press enter, and this gets added to a "total spent" cell in a different tab, making it £10. Later on, I type £125, then after pressing that button, it adds that 125 onto the 10 to make it 135?

Is it also possible to have this input be applied to different cells depending on a name? For example, I want to be able to add concurrent values for a "John" then change it so whatever I type gets added onto "Jill" total instead.

Essentially I'm looking for something like an ongoing data entry/fillable form which is automated by buttons. I hope this makes sense!

I have tried to record a macro which carries out this request, but it only works once, and anything I type in and enter gets replaced after more than 2 attempts.

**The recorded macro**

```
Sub Macro3()
 ' ' Macro3 Macro ' ' 
Range("E23").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "11"
Range("K4").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("B4").Select 
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _ :=False, Transpose:=False
Range("E23").Select Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.ClearContents
End Sub
```

The issue with it is that in this example I used the value "11", so when I push the button assigned macro it only adds 11 rather than a different number I input.

Comment: Yes, it’s possible. Please add the VBA code you have so far.

Comment: The macro I created so far was:
Sub Macro3()
'
' Macro3 Macro
'

'
    Range("E23").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "11"
    Range("K4").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("B4").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("E23").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.ClearContents
End Sub

The issue with it is that in this example I used the value "11", so when I push the button assigned macro it only adds 11 rather than a different number I input.

Comment: With the `Edit` text (under tags) click you can edit your post. I added your code from the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you have two worksheets called `Input` and `Total` as follows:

**Input**

[image: Input worksheet]

**Total**

[image: Total worksheet]

Add a button to the `Input` worksheet with the following code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim Name As Range, Names As Range, Amount As Range
    Dim row As Integer
    
    Set Name = Range("A2")
    Set Amount = Range("B2")
    Set Names = Worksheets("Total").Range("A2:A3")
    
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Names, Name) = 1 Then
        row = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Name, Names, 0) + 1

        With Worksheets("Total")
            .Range("B" & row) = .Range("B" & row) + Amount
        End With
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Notes:

1. The name in `A2` on the `Input` worksheet dictates which person's
   total is updated on the `Total` worksheet
2. Update the variables `Name`, `Amount`, and `Names` to suit your set up
3. Consider adding name validation to the code; here I simply use `Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Names, Name) = 1` to check the name exists in the list on the `Total` worksheet. It assumes there are no duplicate names
4. It may be better to make `A2` on the `Input` worksheet a drop down list of names based on all the names listed on the `Total` worksheet